# Floating point precision and physics calculations

Tags: c#, floating-point, physics

The gravity Vector2 in my physics world is (0; 0.1).

The number 0.1 is known to be problematic, since "it cannot be represented exactly, but is approximately 1.10011001100110011001101 × 2-4".

Having this value for the gravity gives me problems with collisions and creates quite nasty bugs. Changing the value to 0.11 solves these problems.

Is there a more elegant solution that doesn't require changing the value at all?

---

### Video of the bug

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRynch1EtnE

---

### Source code

http://pastebin.com/jNkqa3sg

The first method (AABBIsOverlapping) checks for intersection betweens two AABB entities.
The second method (Update) is called for each body every frame.

I'll try to explain how the Update method works:

1. Add the gravity acceleration vector to the velocity vector
2. Create a temp vector (next) and set it to the velocity
3. Get bodies in the spatial hash in the cells around the current body
4. If there is an horizontal overlap, resolve it, set next.X and velocity.X to 0 and move the player
5. If there is a vertical overlap, resolve it, set next.Y and velocity.Y to 0 (or to 0.1 to prevent constant jumping from ceilings) and move the player
6. After the loop, if there were no overlaps, move the player

Comment: `0.11` can't be represented exactly either.

Comment: Strange... somehow it fixes the problem. My guess is that using 0.11 gives a small enough error that the physics engine is unaffected by it.

Comment: You didn't write anything about how your physics engine works. And that's most likely where the problem lies.

Comment: I'm updating the post with some source code.

Comment: Added. You may also want to see my comment to Krom's reply for more clarifications

Comment: I added a video to the original post... I hope it can be useful to show the problem

Comment: I looked at your code, as best as I can tell you need to round your values to a "grid". Your objects never totally touch - they are always slightly too high, or they overlap. The simplest fix is when you have a collision, manually set the bottom of one object equal to the top of the other. That way they will be at the same spot. You should have posted the code and video from the start. Old questions don't get many replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short no. The usual solution is to never check for equality, and always check for a range +- epsilon (very small value).

Comment: .NET includes appropriate base values [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx) however you should scale this to match the scale of your numbers: see the remarks on the referenced page.

Comment: Never checking for equality is a little strong. There are times when you want to do this, but not if the value you are testing is the result of a floating point calculation. This is none the less good advice, but it's far from clear that it's the root cause of OP's problem.

Comment: @Richard In fact what tolerance value you use when testing depends more on the algorithm used to calculate the number being tested than the scale of that number.

Answer (score 5):

In physics being unable to represent a number shouldn't matter at all. The only thing that matters in physics is the accumulation of rounding errors.

I assume your problem is related to incorrect epsilon comparisons, or even comparisons without epsilon. But without more information I can't help you. If your code can't deal with small rounding errors it is flawed and needs to be fixed.

You could use `Decimal` for your math code, which can represent `0.1m` exactly. But I don't think that's what you really need since your problem is most likely unrelated to the fact that `0.1` can't be represented exactly in `float`.

---

One potential problem I see in your code is that when resolving collisions you move out the body *exactly* to the collision border. Perhaps you need to move it out an epsilon further.

Comment: I'd give this an upvote if it wasn't for the last paragraph which is very misleading.

Comment: In what way is it misleading? `Decimal` can represent `0.1` but it is most likely not the solution to his problem.

Comment: It's misleading because representability is very clearly unrelated to the problem at hand, but since OP has this misconception you are offering a way to prolong that.

Answer (score 2):

If non-representability is resulting in bugs in your code then your algorithms are flawed in some way. It's hard to say how they are flawed because you have not shared any details, but using a representable number won't fix it.

In fact 0.11 is not representable either and so if it solves your problem, it does so for some reason other than this.

Answer (score 2):

In short - You can not work with floating-point values on PC as in real life. There's always gonna be precision loss and rounding errors due to limited amount of memory used to store the values within very wide ranges.

Always check for equality with some epsilon which could be half the step between working values, e.g. 0.1:

```
IsEqual(0.1, 0.2, 0.05) = false
IsEqual(0.1, 0.1001, 0.05) = true
IsEqual(0.1, 0.1499, 0.05) = true
```

or best precision at given scale and given floating-point format (e.g. 64bit has smaller epsilon than 32bit obviously) (you may need to check with your language for ways to obtaining that value):

```
IsEqual(0.1, 0.2, BestPrecisionAt(0.1)) = false
IsEqual(0.1, 0.1001, BestPrecisionAt(0.1)) = false
IsEqual(0.1, 0.1499, BestPrecisionAt(0.1)) = false
IsEqual(0.1, 0.1000001, BestPrecisionAt(0.1)) = true
//Where for example BestPrecisionAt(0.1) could be 0.00001
```

**EDIT:** 
You said nothing about bugs you are having. So what is exactly wrong with 0.1?
I could only assume that your timestep is not precise enough, your objects speeds allow them to pass through each other inbetween collision checks. Is that correct? If yes - you should increase timestep resolution and/or check for collisions earlier.

Comment: "So what is exactly wrong with 0.1?" -> It works perfectly unless the body is exactly at Y 128. If it is at Y 128 and there's an obstacle under it, it starts shaking. 

It also has problems at Y 32: everything is pushed out horizontally. Game-breaking problem.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong - you may take a look at the source code, I added it in the original post

Comment: That looks like at certain levels errors accumulate and each time step rounds/compares/reverses the values wrongly. Check your epsilon and timestep.

Comment: I'm not using any epsilon or checking timestep... How and where should I do that?

Comment: I added a video to the original post... I hope it can be useful to show the problem

Comment: Add one cube and trace into your code in debug mode. See why it does not stays still. Probably some bug..

Comment: I think I found the problem: float top = (body.CornerMin.Y - nextCornerMax.Y); should calculate the Y penetration. When the bug occurs -> top = (32 - 32.1) -> top = 0.99...~ //// so I think that since the entity isn't totally pushed up from the ground the next frame it gets pushed out horizontally... How can I prevent this? 32 - 32.1 should just be -0.1!

Comment: Wait... The same thing occurs in any other Y position. So that can't be the problem. I'm totally stuck here :(

Comment: I debugged for about an hour... Couldn't find anything else. I'm pretty sure the problem is floating point precision. You were talking about an epsilon before, where do I introduce it?